# Is it possible to untrack a file in git w/o removing it in the remotes

Tags: git

I would like to have the following when working with git, but not sure if it's possible:

- I have `results.log` file where program execution results are recorded (appended on subsequent executions).
- `main.conf` includes the location, where `results.log` is located.
- It would be beneficial to keep `results.log` file empty in git and add a relative path to it in `main.conf` so when the project is checked out, the colleague could immediately launch the program and have results.
- After the launche(s) the file should be tracked, so it would not be commited with the data generated by the application.

I thought the following sequence of actions would work:

- Add an empty file;
- Commit, push to origin;
- Add the file to git ignore;

But after theses steps the file is still being tracked (since it is in the index tree). `git rm --cached <>` removes it entirelly from the origin when `push` is performed.

**Question**: is what I want is possible and if so, how to do it?

Comment: Sounds to me like your application should simply create an empty `results.log` if the file is not found. Then you don't have to hack around it in git and can just stop tracking it.

Comment: Yes, that would be possible, however I encountered this need in multiple situations. It seems to me like this approach would facilitate faster setup and initial runs of the application w/o any code.

Comment: We're straying into other issues here, but if deleting an empty file causes your application to stop working, that's a defect. It shouldn't be the responsibility of the VCS to get your application into a runnable state. You either need a setup script or the application should self-configure in some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a [pre-commit hook](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) that runs

```
git reset --soft results.log
```

This ensures that the file can never be committed, though with two caveats:

1. It will always show up as "Changes to be committed" under `git status`. Might be kind of annoying
2. You need to ensure that every developer installs this same hook to avoid committing the log. Might be really annoying

To be fair, what you want is by definition a hack: you want git to track this file so that every developer has it, but you don't want git to track it because every developer will have different file contents. There isn't going to be a "clean" solution (other than my comment on your question).

Comment: Thank you, a confirmation that it is not possible and why its better to keep it that way is more than fine! :)